# How to find a GCP account that owns a VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

I have a VM (my own) that I spawned from the Google Cloud account I can't recall. I tried all I have in my password manager but I still can't find the account it belongs to.

I have full remote desktop access (Win Server 2012) and no freaking idea how to sort it out.

Comment: Did you mean you want to find the user/account that created the VM?
The VM belongs to the project not to a specific person so in order to login to it you just need to access the Cloud Console with an user that has at least Compute Engine Admin role https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.instanceAdmin.v1
Please clarify if I didn't understand your question

Comment: VM > Project > Cloud Account, that's the simplified nesting level I understand

My problem is that I can't find the "Cloud Account" for the VM I have on file. I already reached out to the support, but maybe there's a more straightforward way I'm not aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having problems to understand what you mean by Google Account that "owns" a VM. VMs are resources for a project where you can have 1 or more project Owners but there isn't a role "VM owner" I'm adding a couple of possible scenarios for what you might intend to do.

> Find the user who created the instance.

1. Go to stackdriver Logging
2. Use [Advanced Filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) with this filter:

protoPayload.serviceName="compute.googleapis.com"
protoPayload.methodName="beta.compute.instances.insert"
protoPayload.request.disks.deviceName="INSTANCE-NAME"

3. Open the entry and search for **principalEmail** and that is the account
   who created the instance.

***These logs only last for 6 months**

> Find Project Owner or users that can access the VM

In [IAM page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-console) search for members with one of the following roles

```
Project Owner

Project Editor

Compute Admin

Compute Instance Admin
```

> I have a user account on my instance level and I want to map it to an
>   email address.

Lets says that under Computer Management > Users you found a user account johndoe and you want to map it to an actual email address from your project.

a) If the account was manually added to the server through basic Windows user management then there is no way to know the email address.

b)If the user account was created through [GCP  Windows instance password creation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-passwords-for-windows-instances) process then you should be able to map the user johndoe to an email address from the IAM page explained in the previous scenario.